# No link works after magento 1.9.1 sample data installed

Tags: magento-1.9

Installed lattest magento 1.9.1 and sample data on parallel plesk and everything look ok except no link works on front end. Backend is fine.
here is the link
http://munchmeonline.co.uk/ap1/
I am new to Magento.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the sample data.
You don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your system.
If you take a look at [this link](http://munchmeonline.co.uk/ap1/index.php/accessories.html) you will see it works.
You either need to enable `mod_rewrite` or make magento use `index.php` in your url, after the base url and before the url key.
For this second option, look in the table `core_config_data` for a record with the  `path` = 'web/seo/use_rewrites' and set it's value to `0`. clear the cache when you are done.